# TypeError: this.props.obj is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass an object from a child to a parent component and here is the code for it:

Header class

```
class Header extends React.Component{
    render()
    {
      return(
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            {this.props.text}
            {this.props.num}
            Hello
            </a>
            <div>
            {this.props.myObj.a}
            </div>

            {JSON.stringify(this.props.myObj)}

        </header>
      )
    }
}
```

App class which uses the above mentioned Header component

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
    // <Header text="Dynamix "/>
    <Header num={10} myObj={{
      a: 1 ,
      b: 2
    }}/>
    <Body/>
    <Body2/>
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: this.props.myObj is undefined
 <div> 
^ 37 | {this.props.myObj.a}
  38 | </div>
  39 |
```

The only problem is the line: `{this.props.myObj.a}`. There was no issue with any other variable that I sent. I am new to React and javascript in general so please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment part was not correct. (you can not comment like this). if it is intentional then you need to pass the object. here is the updated code. You can check the working link https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-waterfall-eo8j8?file=/src/App.js:0-321

```
import React from "react";
    import "./styles.css";
    import { Header } from "./Header";
    export class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <Header
              num={10}
              myObj={{
                a: 1,
                b: 2
              }}
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

---- Header component updated.

```
import React from "react";
export class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={this.props.logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          {this.props.text}
          {this.props.num}
          Hello
        </a>
        <div>{this.props?.myObj?.a}</div>

        {JSON.stringify(this.props.myObj)}
      </header>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you elaborate a little more on why the '?'  was added ahead of props and myObj? And at the same time why is it not used for any other text and not used in JSON.stringify either?

Comment: ? Does null or undefined check, I added one place. You can add in all other places.